# How to permanently update the table structure after joining few columns from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 5 columns, I am joining with another table that has 2 columns. (based on 1 common column) 
Now I got all the 5 columns from table1 and 1 extra column from table2 after Join.

Expected: 
I need my table1 structure to be the result of my join. (i.e) How can I update my table structure after the join. I require all the 6 columns to be table 1

Comment: You can't mix DDL and DML.  What do you mean you want to update table structure based on the result of join?

Comment: Can you show some images to clearify? :) would help alot

Comment: Use a view.  There is no need to change the table structure.

Comment: Initially, my table has 5 columns. As the result of join it is 6 columns now. I need my 6th column (that I got from join) to be in my table1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a view:

```
create v_table1 as
    select t1.*, t2.col
    from table1 t1 join
         table2 t2
         on . . . ;
```

This is handy.  When `table2` changes, then the view will "automatically" reflect the changes.

If you wanted to add a new column to `table1` and update it once, you would do:

```
alter table table1 add <new column> <column definition>;

update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on . . .
    set t1.<new column> = t2.col;
```

However, this sets the value once -- when run.

Comment: The reason I need it as a new table structure is, I have many other data manipulations to be done on the result set.